# VS Solution in custom cmake target sometimes hangs

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cmake

I've expirienced the promlem using CMake. I need to use VS solution (.sln) in one target, so I have something like that:

```
set(SLN "${SOME_PATH}/src/exemple.sln")
get_filename_component(
    VS_DIR "[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\VisualStudio\\10.0\\Setup\\VS;ProductDir]"
    REALPATH CACHE)
set(BUILD_TOOL "${VS_DIR}/Common7/IDE/devenv.exe")

set(BUILD_COMMAND
    "${BUILD_TOOL}" "${SLN}" "/build" "Debug"
    )

add_custom_target(
    ${Project_OUTPUT}
    COMMAND ${BUILD_COMMAND}
    VERBATIM
    )
```

And sometimes this target (when it is being compiled) hangs. Does someone know what it might be? Maybe it doesn't depend on CMake? According to logs, build system starts few projects (from this solution) and does nothing after that:

```
26>------ Build started: Project: project26, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
27>------ Build started: Project: project27, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
28>------ Build started: Project: project28, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
29>------ Build started: Project: project29, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to specify devenv.com instead of devenv.exe. See the output of the following commands:

```
E:\folder>devenv.exe "E:\folder\solution.sln" /build Debug

E:\folder>devenv.com "E:\folder\solution.sln" /build Debug

Microsoft (R) Visual Studio Version 10.0.40219.1.
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. All rights reserved.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

E:\folder>
```

Comment: Actually, what's the difference between devenv.exe and devenv.com?

Comment: Good question. See this page for more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee0c8y7(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: I found hot fix from Microsoft for this exact issue: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2444922/en . But it is unbelievable (or may be not) - it doesn't help me. The bug is still there.

Comment: Did you try to replace `set(BUILD_TOOL "${VS_DIR}/Common7/IDE/devenv.exe")` by `set(BUILD_TOOL "${VS_DIR}/Common7/IDE/devenv.com")`?